# High-resolution Lunar Topography import into QGIS. Float img format?

Tags: qgis, dem, floating-point

I don't know how to import these float img files into QGIS

https://pgda.gsfc.nasa.gov/products/54

Ultimately I want to be able to export them as 16bit PNG's but I'm stuck now knowing how to import them in the first instance

QGIS version
3.24.0-Tisler

Comment: Better download this file in JPEG2000 format and add it as a raster layer. This way works fine with QGIS.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what were your results?